# DispatcherTimer Constructors

Tags: c#, wpf

How come in some classes I have to specify this constructor to get the callback to be invoked?

`_timer = new DispatcherTimer(DispatcherPriority.Normal, Application.Current.Dispatcher);`

Instead of just:

`_timer = new DispatcherTimer();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default constructor will use the current Dispatcher instead of the current application's Dispatcher.  If this is called on a thread other than the UI thread, the first overload is required in order to get the correct synchronization context.